# MySQL Python Error 1064, Error in MySQL Sytax

Tags: python, mysql, connector

Im currently having some issues when im trying to insert a line into a database, this also worked before though it is only now that I have added the "key" column it fails to work and gives me an error.

```
add = ("INSERT INTO server_stats_servers "
            "(Owner, ServerID, MessageID, Channel, ServerIP, ServerPort, ServerName, DiscordName, Key)"
            "VALUES (%(Owner)s, %(ServerID)s, %(MessageID)s, %(Channel)s, %(ServerIP)s, %(ServerPort)s, %(ServerName)s, %(DiscordName)s, %(Key)s)")
    values = {"Owner": owner,
            "ServerID": serverid,
            "MessageID": messageid,
            "Channel": channel,
            "ServerIP": ip,
            "ServerPort": port,
            "ServerName": servername,
            "DiscordName": discordname,
            "Key": key,}
    cursor.execute(add, values)
    cnx.commit()
```

Error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Key')VALUES ('Modern_Mo', '349692657221500938', '505375472646094868', '48783440' at line 1
```

Any help is great! (All of these inputs are Strings, aswell the "key" is specified as "modern")

Comment: did you try to do the insert manually using a mysql client ?

Comment: Maybe because Key is a reserved keyword, or the hanging comma,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KEY` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. You must quote it in your query when used as an identifier:

```
add = ("INSERT INTO server_stats_servers (Owner, ServerID, MessageID, "
       "Channel, ServerIP, ServerPort, ServerName, DiscordName, `Key`) "
       "VALUES (%(Owner)s, %(ServerID)s, %(MessageID)s, %(Channel)s, "             
       "%(ServerIP)s, %(ServerPort)s, %(ServerName)s, %(DiscordName)s, %(Key)s)")
```

Comment: I attempted placing quotes on it, which failed.
Instead I renamed "Key" to "KeyUsed" which worked.
Thank you very much for your assistance and quick response!

Comment: Note that the identifier quote character is the backtick `\``, not `'` :)